# Creating image with in the frame of a rectangle placed on a UIImageview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

How to create a new image with specified frame in a UIView, the view contains imageviews and buttons also.I also need to get the image in the specified frame as a new image.
I've tried this but it not correct.

I need to crop from UIView and make it as a new UIImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import this framework in your project.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And use following code

```
[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0]; // set border width as per your requirement.
```

**EDITED:**

Use any one which you need.

**For Get Crop Image:**

```
UIImage *croppedImg = nil;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(AS YOu Need);
croppedImg = [self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:cropRect];
```

Use following method that return `UIImage` (*as You want size of image*)

```
- (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        //CGRect CropRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height+15);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        return cropped;
    }
```

Here you get Croped Image that return by above method;

**OR RESIZING**

And also Use following method for specific **hight** and **width** with **image** for **Resizing UIImage**:

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you want.

Comment: sorry this not gives the required solution.

Comment: I need to crop from UIView and make it as a new UIImage.

Comment: yes I need to crop image from UIView with in a specified frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I want to crop UIView (that contains different imageview)