# Memory problems with a function I created IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this function to crop an image and when I use it, it doesn't release memory, I tried not using it and the memory works fine.I can't seem to find the problem with it.Please help

```
- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image {
haveImage = YES;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];


__weak UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height - ((image.size.height - image.size.width)/2));
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);

__weak UIImage *corteSuperior =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

cropRect = CGRectMake(0, ((image.size.height - image.size.width)/2), corteSuperior.size.width, corteSuperior.size.height - ((image.size.height - image.size.width)/2));
imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([corteSuperior CGImage], cropRect);



 self.imagenCamara.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];



smallImage = nil;
imageRef = nil;
corteSuperior = nil;

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

}
```

Comment: For other tips for see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042819/creating-image-with-in-the-frame-of-a-rectangle-placed-on-a-uiimageview

Comment: BTW, you have one call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and two calls to `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`. You might want to remove that second call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `CGImageRelease` call for each `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` call. You're never releasing the first occurrence. Before you assign `imageRef` the second time, release the first `imageRef`.

Also, at the end, make sure you perform the `CGImageRelease` before you `nil` the `imageRef` pointer. By setting `imageRef` to `nil`, you're losing your reference to the `imageRef`, and thus the `CGImageRelease` will be unable to release anything.

Comment: TIP : If you use XCode Static analyzer, it should display these kinds of errors to you !